# Who felt this character in The Last Jedi dying?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

As we know,

> Luke

dies at the end of The Last Jedi, without immediate witnesses. I'm assuming that it might be possible in principle for other force-aware people to feel this.

My question is simply: Who felt that character die? In particular, does his main adversary know, by which I mean:

> Does Kylo Ren know?

Comment: Leia should have felt it. After all she did when Hans died in The Force Awakens. Even Rey may have.

Comment: Given we see Rey and Leia feel it, there’s 2

Comment: @Edlothiad, I think the most interesting question is whether the villain(s) know about it ;)

Comment: Well that’s not what you’re asking, maybe you should edit that to make it clear

Comment: Out of universe, it probably wouldn't make sense for Kylo Ren not to know; it would make for a pretty boring third movie if he spent all his time obsessed with chasing someone who is already dead.  Inconclusive, which is why I'm not posting an answer, but suggestive.  I guess we'll find out for sure in 2019.

Comment: @Shreedhar What? Hans Olo died in _The Force Awakens_? Nobody ever tells me anything!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. **Leia and Rey.**

   On the Falcon, right after Rey observes Finn cover his gf with a blanket (exposing the Jedi texts), Leia sits next to Rey and they talk quietly:

   > REY: Luke is gone. I felt it. ... There was peace... and purpose.
   >
   > LEIA: I felt it too

   (*transcription mine because S.U. Disney for not releasing novelization*)
2. As far as everyone else knows, except Kylo Ren, Luke was killed in a heroic battle (recreated by the kids on Canto Bright) to buy the embers of the Resistance time to escape.

   The only ones who witnessed it were First Order soldiers with Kylo Ren, who saw (from their viewpoint) Kylo run Luke through with a lightsaber a second after which he disintegrated into thin air. They didn't hear Luke's "see you around, kid" taunt.

   Kylo isn't explicitly shown as knowing, but as he observed the dice disappearing, he **may** have known as well. We need more confirmation though.

Answer (score 2):

There's no concrete evidence yet, but we can make at least one reasonable assumption: **Leia**. She's shown to have an innate ability to sense such things several times already in the series:

- She sensed Luke's peril and was able to locate him beneath Cloud City at the end of Empire Strikes Back.
- She knew that Luke was safe after the destruction of Death Star II, before he arrived back on Endor.
- She was visibly very distressed the moment Han was killed, despite him being halfway across the galaxy.

Comment: Found concrete evidence in the actual film dialog :)

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Care to share?

Comment: - see my answer's update :)

Answer (score 2):

### Kylo Ren doesn't know.

According to the film's [official junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_A_Junior_Novel), all he knows is that Luke played a trick on him.

> Ren’s hand began to tremble. The stormtroopers hurried away from him. He examined the antiquated command center consoles.
>   He picked up two small objects from the ground. A pair of chance cubes, strung together. Ren knew the dice well. They had been Han’s, hanging in the cockpit of—
>   The Millennium Falcon. Ren glimpsed the ship through the Force. **Rey and Leia were boarding. Both seemed upset by something.**

Without any evidence to the contrary, we can assume that he thinks that Luke is still alive.

Answer (score 1):

There's a heavy implication that

> Kylo Ren knew as well. Not only does he get duped by Luke's Force projection, there's a scene where he picks up Han's dice from the Millennium Falcon (also a projection that Luke had handed to Leia) and they disappear in his hand. Given how force sensitive he is, he likely also felt Luke's death, as it appears to have sent ripples through the Force (hence Rey and Leia mourning Luke). Being one of the few who knew the truth, he likely connected the two.

Comment: I disagree. I read the moment you hide in the spoiler tag as simple reinforcing the shame of being blinded by rage in the first place.

Comment: @scott I think that's true, but it doesn't exclude him realizing it as well. There's no mutual exclusion there